# Using query result in another query

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables: `cc_claim`, `cc_exposure`, `cc_new`

I am trying to select the `claimID` from `cc_claim` by `claimNumber` and then use that `ID` to retrieve an `exposureID` from the `cc_exposure` table. Then finally I want to select the column from `cc_new` table that has that `exposureID`. Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT cc_claim.ID as test
FROM cc_claim
where ClaimNumber ='19D1000011'
JOIN (cc_exposure where AssignedUserID = test)
```

I am not sure if I am on the right track.. new to sql.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be what you had in mind:

```
SELECT c.ID AS test
FROM cc_claim c
INNER JOIN cc_exposure ex
    ON c.ID = ex.AssignedUserID
WHERE c.ClaimNumber = '19D1000011';
```

Note that `JOIN` always comes *after* `FROM`, and before the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks... what I'm trying to do is grab a value called AssignedUser from the cc_exposure table after I join the table by claimnumber. Is that possible?

Comment: @iceMan33 what you are trying to do is still unclear because you did not post all the info needed: column names for all the tables involved and column references for each table, as well as sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

you need to join the tables on the matching Ids to get what you need.

```
 SELECT cc_claim.ID as test,new.exposureId
    FROM cc_claim c
    Inner JOIN cc_exposure ex
        ON c.ID = ex.AssignedUserID
    Inner JOIN  cc_new new
     ON ex.exposureId=new.exposureID

    where c.ClaimNumber ='19D1000011'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.